# Bi-directional motor driver amplifier

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, dc-motor

I am using circuit2 scheme to control direction of a actuator. When `control1 == 0 && control2 == 1 or control1 == 1 && control2 == 0` it is not working.

I have measured voltage on NPN amplifiers which emitters are connected to driving transistors bases and it is high on both control lines in both cases (`control1 == 0 && control2 == 1 or control1 == 1 && control2 == 0`). This behaviour blocks circuit function as when both control lines are high it will not work.

Please any ideas what is wrong with that?

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of Q9 and Q10?

Answer (score 1):

Your black negative image could not be seen so I converted it into a normal positive image with black lines on a white background.
The inputs must be opposites high and low for the motor to run. If both inputs are high or low then the motor does not run.
The emitter-followers reduce the output voltage.
[image: motor H-bridge]

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you are unaware that CONTROL1 and CONTROL2 must be significantly higher than 5 volts and significantly lower than ground for the circuit to work well.

But not too much.

If CONTROL1 is high enough to turn on Q1 (saturation voltage ~0.2 volts), the base of Q1 will need to be at least 0.5 volts above +5, so the base of Q8 will need to be about 0.7 above that, for a total of about 1.2 volts.

Likewise, CONTROL2 needs to be about 1.2 volts below ground to turn on Q4 all the way.

And if you make them much more than that, you'll get current feeding the +5 and ground lines via the base-collector junctions of Q1 and Q4.